# How to limit the number of Azure B2C verification emails

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there any configuration present in Azure B2C to limit the number of verification emails ( *used for email verification during create account & reset password workflows* ) sent to users in a specified time window aka rate limit. We want to prevent malicious actors email bombing our customers with these verification emails.

Comment: Currently there is no way to configure the email verification rate limit.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a retry limit in the selfasserted page if using Custom Policies. It will force the user to be sent back to the app, and they have to try the process again.

`setting.retryLimit`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#metadata

The service itself has some throttling limits on how many can be sent from a particular IP within a certain timeframe.

Comment: Can you point me to any documentation related to rate limit?

Comment: We do not publish our rate limits to prevent it being taken advantage of.

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_0IIS6ADn0GecsMB&Q_CHL=gl
>

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT, findings from a penetration test suggest that there is no rate limit applied to the password reset flow, and that this can be used to spam reset emails. If you are able to provide any official documentation that confirms the presence of a rate limit (even if it does not specify what the limit is) that would be very helpful, as right now I am being told the opposite is true.